# regex js for application[0].customer_id

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to know how to get this 3 elements with regex;
Despite to know very basic regex, when i have[] i get in problems

type of expression have 3 parts:

application[0].customer_id

1. application (before [
2. number 0 inside []
3. string after []

I've tried this:

```
 /(a-z)\[[0-9]\])(a-z)?/;
```

but it's not working.

Comment: [`(\w+)\[(\d+)]\.(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/Dn5VBj/1)?

Comment: Sample here: https://regex101.com/r/T2Xe7a/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use groups `()` then you can get each group returning from `match` or `replace`.

```js
var str = "application[0].customer_id";

var found = str.match(/(\w+)\[([0-9]+)\]\.(\w+)/);

console.log(found[1])
console.log(found[2])
console.log(found[3])
```